# Listbox Items in Multiple Columns in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, listbox

I'm trying to get the items of each listbox in each row in each column. I've been advised to use the "FindVisualChildren" method/function but am unable to call it from my button onclick event. I get error...

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Controls.ListBox>' to 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
```

and am not sure how to handle it.

```
public static IEnumerable<childItem> FindVisualChildren<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) where childItem : DependencyObject
    {
        // Search immediate children
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

            if (child is childItem)
                yield return (childItem)child;

            else
            {
                var childOfChild = FindVisualChildren<childItem>(child);

                if (childOfChild != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in childOfChild)
                    {
                        yield return item;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        yield return null;
    }
```

and I'm calling it using...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // Update Job Step Grid ListBox
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridJobSteps.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject obj = dataGridJobSteps.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            ListBox _listBox = FindVisualChildren<ListBox>(obj);

            if (_listBox != null)
            {
                var selectedItems = _listBox.Items;
                foreach (var selectedItem in selectedItems)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I should be using MVVM, but that is turning out to be a steep learning curb for me and I need to get this piece of code implemented to go forward... any help appreciated.

Image of what I'm trying to do...There are foreign keys in DB associated to one primary and two secondary db tables. My grid contains multiple rows of data and within each row there is a list of possible ListBox Items over two columns. One for Potential Incidents and Hazards and one for Controls and Checks Required. User is able to add/remove rows to primary and then add/remove items to these two columns. Please let me know if you require further info.

**PS. There are other user controls on the same parent control**

[image: Datagrid]

Comment: WPF is not intended to be used like this. WPF is not suitable for developers with a procedural, code-behind mentality. the `DataGrid` and most other `ItemsControl`s are complex UI elements which create and destroy their visual children dynamically as per the built-in UI virtualization. Your procedural approach will always fail, because you're trying to read data from the UI (instead of using proper databinding) while the UI has not even been created for those Data items yet.

Comment: MVVM is not "hard". MVVM is just *Simple, Simple Properties and `INotifyPropertyChanged`*. It is in NO way harder than this horrible, procedural approach you're attempting here, which btw doesn't even work and will NOT work.

Comment: Simply create a Row ViewModel for each DataGrid Row containing ObservableCollections for each ListBox and a SelectedItem property for each selected item. I don't see what the big deal is.

Comment: **the UI is not responsible for storing your data nor maintaing it's state**. You should create a proper DataModel and ViewModel to hold the state of Data Items and Presentation items respectively, while leaving the UI alone.

Comment: You're just wasting your time by trying these procedural approaches in WPF. You will simply fail. If you wish, post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: Hello HighCore... I've added the image and explanation of what I'm trying to do. Regarding MVVM... I'm in the process of investigating the use of Caliburn.Micro, but as usual there is not enough sample/info/how to do's that cover "end to end" development. Any recommendations on end to end examples most welcome. IE. From bootstrapping to publishing your app. Specific to data capturing screen type apps...

Answer (score 0):

The error states what's wrong. Try taking first element from the list,as so:

```
ListBox _listBox = FindVisualChildren<ListBox>(obj).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I then added "if (_listBox != null) {...}". It compiles but I don't get any results returned. PS I've used the "FindVisualChild" and it returns the first column listbox items but not the second col... hence the "FindVisualChildren"